# Finding out if compass sensors has low accuracy

Tags: android, ios, cllocationmanager, android-sensors

I'm currently integrating a Compass View in our Android and iOS application. As expected, the sensor values are not always perfect. It is not that big of a problem but it would be nice to warn the user if the sensors are inaccurate. So is there any way to figure out if the sensors has low accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, in the `SensorEventListener` there is a function `onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy)` in which you can check the accuracy of the device's magnetometer. There are 4 levels of accuracy (See the [`SensorManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) class):

```
SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH = 3 
SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_MEDIUM = 2
SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_LOW = 1 
SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE = 0
```

I'm not sure how to do that on ios though.

This information is also available for each SensorEvent received in `onSensorChanged`.

Comment: At least for the `ROTATION_VECTOR` sensor type, it keeps reporting `ACCURACY_HIGH` even when it's obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the Sensor accuracy is supplied with each update. A headingAccuracy < 0 means that the value is wrong. If it's > 0, it indicates the maximum deviation between the value and the true value and one can define a threshold.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    NSLog(@"LocationManager did update Heading with accuracy %g", newHeading.headingAccuracy);
    if(newHeading.headingAccuracy < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Invalid value!");
    } else if(newHeading.headingAccuracy < ACCURACY_THRESHOLD) {
        NSLog(@"Too low Accuracy!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Accuracy is good enough to use value");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `ACCURACY_THRESHOLD` here?

Comment: The headingAccuracy is measured as a deviation in degrees (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading/1423705-headingaccuracy)

and ACCURACY_THRESHOLD is your own constant defining what deviation you accept. So for example if you're only interested in the NWSE, a deviation of maybe 45 degrees is fine. If you are using it for a more specific purpose, you should use a lower threshold.